# MacBook early 2009 power issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I have been on here quite a lot with all my issues. I have a project MacBook (early 2009, a1181, which is running OSX High sierra and Ubuntu along with a bootloader, refit or fEFInd, can't remember at the moment). The macbook gets really hot when charging, so much so that my friend got a burn just from picking it up!

The heat is on the bottom corner closest to the MagSafe port. The MacBook randomly shuts down and it takes longer for it to shut down when it starts up cold.

The shut down is so abrupt that you can hear the hard drive's arm clunk. When I try to power it on again, the indicator light turns on for a split second but goes out (hard drive also clunks as soon as the light goes out).

Is this a power issue? If you think you know how to fix it, please let me know!

Comment: Also I replaced the battery yesterday, but nothing changed.

Comment: When it's hot, is it running or not?  The shutdown you described is like losing power, so it's possible that your [MagSafe board](https://amzn.to/2sHkNO6) might have failed - you may also be in the process of frying the SMC circuitry (logic board).  Also, you said you changed the battery, so it's difficult to know what you did or didn't do.

Comment: It gets hot from charging. I've reset the smc and pram and still no difference

Comment: It charges when it's running or not so that doesn't answer the question.  NVRAM has nothing to do with charging and clearing the values of the SMC doesn't fix physical issues with the circuit.

Comment: It charges while running.

Comment: But even though it does run, it eventually shuts down with a clunking hard drive? Does it shut down even when you're not actively using it and it is just sitting there?  From your description of the symptoms, there is some serious hardware problem inside this MacBook. I don't think that anybody here can give you a definitive diagnosis from where we sit. Because it generates enough heat to burn a human being, that is cause enough to get it looked at by a professional. As for the burned friend, take two pain-relievers and apply ice.

Comment: He took 2 Aleve and put a he11 of a lot of biofreeze on it. If you don't know what Bioreeze is, it's a pain released for sore muscles that freezes the affected area. Anyway, the macbook does it while I'm there or not. Do you think a logic board replacement out of a parts-only macbook off of ebay will do the trick? And while I'm at it, do you think i could put a logic board with an upgraded core 2 duo processor in it?